# Export Billing Data to BigQuery not Working

Tags: google-bigquery

To track BQ usage we created a new dataset and  configured it in Billing export. But after waiting for a day also the dataset seems to be empty as no new tables is created.

Is there any other setup needs to be done for this to work.

Refer this link,

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery

Thanks and regards,
Gour

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow the [How to enable billing export to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery#how_to_enable_billing_export_to_bigquery_name_short) steps to begin using this functionality. Keep in mind that you have to wait certain time to start seeing your data, as mentioned in the **Export Billing Data to BigQuery** documentation.

> After you enable BigQuery export, it might take a few hours to start seeing your data. Billing data automatically exports your data to BigQuery in regular intervals, but the frequency of updates in BigQuery varies depending on the services you're using.

In case you continue having this issue, I recommend you to take a look the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#bug_reports) tool that you can use to raise a [BigQuery ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#bug_reports) in order to verify this scenario with the Google Technical Support Team. Since this is an automated process, you might need some of their help to review your Project's internal configuration.

Comment: Yes you are right. but I don't find anything being updated in the new dataset created as sink for the BQ usage. Last resort is to raise a support ticket with google to see if anything else is needed.

Comment: That's correct, I think you should proceed on contacting Google Support since it might be required to check your project configuration to verify is there is an issue as you have followed the steps required to enable this feature

Comment: Any update on this? We had enabled the export, which was working fine. It suddenly stopped after 6 weeks of collecting data. No clue about what happened.

Comment: @Nebulastic Unfortunately all signs suggest that it is indeed not possible to export billing data to bigquery. It may be a bug, but given that this SO question has been open so long it is probably deliberate.